# Mysterious objects in Debug View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, debugview

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm seeing in the Debug View Hierarchy. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The question is what are all the seemingly extraneous views (highlighted in blue)? I'm particularly interested in the one in front of the red view.

The point here is that while these things show up in the Debug View Hierarchy, they're not visible in the Storyboard Editor, nor are they identified in the Document Online. They're sort of cryptically identified in the Debug Navigator (the one in question is identified as a generic UIView). I'm not aware of adding these things in Storyboard, and they're muddying the water in my debugging efforts.

All help or observations appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Some UIKit components are quite complex view hierarchies behind the scenes.  It's the internal Apple implementation. You might see simple UIViews or more esoteric stuff like UITableViewWrapperView. Unfortunately there is no easy way to turn visibility of these off.